The container is not starting rancher
Good afternoon, I ran into the problem that the rancher container does not start.
Here is the command I use
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 rancher/rancher --privileged

I've tried different launch options, even through compose, but an error always pops up.
ERROR: Rancher must be ran with the --privileged flag when running outside of Kubernetes

but I'm already using the --privileged argument in the command.
I'm trying to run the container inside a virtual machine that runs through ProxMox
ProxMox
pve-manager/8.2.2/9355359cd7afbae4 (running kernel: 6.8.4-2-pve)

ubuntu
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


try docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --privileged rancher/rancher:latest

It didn't work out

Your problem is that you are adding privileged flag at the end of your command, this makes it that your flag is being sent as a CMD to the docker container instead of docker cli.
Thats because docker run template looks like this:
docker container run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

use this command instead:
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --privileged rancher/rancher

